# Write file to external storage so that the user can access from file storage

Tags: android

I want to write a `.txt` file to the phone so the user can access from file storage
This is what I have so far, but I found out it was only available to my app.

```
path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS); 
public void Print() {

        String print = "text"
                printstring(print);
    }

public void printstring(String s) {
    try {
        File file = new File(path, "fileName.txt");
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fileOutputStream);
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(outputStreamWriter);
        
        bufferedWriter.write(s);

        bufferedWriter.close();
        outputStreamWriter.close();
        fileOutputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText( MainActivity.getAppContext() , "Toast", 1000).show();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);

Comment: Put that statement in your post please. If your app can write to that path every app has access. Is the file written? Put a Toast in that catch block.

Comment: I need the user to be able to go the the directory and access it. not just the apps.

Comment: All apps can have access. If the user wants to go to that directory an app has to be used. Or not? Please tell how the user travels.

Comment: I would like them to go into my app, put in the information. then hit button that generates the file. then the file needs to be accessible for them to do things like send it to a printer or over an email.

Comment: That is all possible. No problem if the file is created. Then you only need some code to share your file. You did not post such code. But all starts with that the file is really written. You did not react on my toast suggestion so i still dont know if everything goes as you want.

Comment: `so the user can access from file storage ` Well that is very different from what you said in your last comment. Confusing.

Comment: i change it becuse others said from other apps and I was more thinking you go into My File/ Documents. and I never did a toast before so I'm trying to figure that out

Comment: why is there something else I should be trying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for those that need the answer, I figured it out.

```
public void printstring(String print) {
    try {
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), "filename.txt");
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(fileOutputStream);
        printWriter.write(print);


        printWriter.close();
        fileOutputStream.close();

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.getAppContext(), "save successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.getAppContext(), "Toast", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
```

then I need the following in the Manifest

```
 <application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" ... </application>
```

on top of the user permissions